# Does this sequence of Bernoulli experiments succeed after finitely many experiments?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider the sequence $(\epsilon_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $0 \leq \epsilon_n \leq 1$ which satisfies $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \epsilon_n = \infty$.
Let $X_n$ be independent Bernoulli-distributed random variables with success probability $\epsilon_n$.

Is it true that with probability $1$, $X_n = 1$ for some finite $n \in \mathbb{N}$?
That is, almost surely, it does not take infinitely long for the "first" coin flip to succeed.

Intuitively, I would expect this as $\epsilon_n$ does not decay quickly.

Can we also say something about the second, third, … successful coin flip?

Comment: Borel Cantelli Lemma shows that with probability $1$, $X_n=1$ for infinitely many values of $n$.

Comment: @geetha290krm yes but does this imply that w.p. 1, the first such n (or maybe even the first k) is finite? Sorry if the answer is stupidly simple